# Mysqlhook.get_records saves boolean as b'\00' and b'\01' values, while I need tinyint format

Tags: python, sql, airflow

I am using mysqlhook to copy data from one server to another. However, in the output database, the boolean data format is TINYINT(1), while the boolean data format in my source table is bit(1).
I use the myselhook.get_records function to read the source data and the mysqlhook_insert_rows to write to the output table. I am doing this generically for many tables and therefore, I can't convert the data types manyally per column, but need some general data type conversion.
I tried the

```
set GLOBAL sql_mode = "";
```

command already and while this removed the data type error, all values in the output table were set to 0, while there should be 1's as well.